# how can i make relation between two fields with different django classes?

Tags: python, django

i have two models "Club" class and "Match" class and it has foreign key to Club
but i can not increment "won" field (or draw or lost) in "Club" class by "score_local" and "score_visitor" in "Match" class ..
how can i do this

```
class Club(models.Model):
    league_names = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='club')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/core', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    year_of_establishment = models.IntegerField(default=1900)
    won = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    draw = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lost = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def CalcPoints(self):
         return self.won*3 + self.draw            

    total_points = property(CalcPoints)

class Match(models.Model):
    play_date = models.DateTimeField('play date')
    occasion = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match')
    club_visitor = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_club_visitor')
    club_local = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_club_local')
    score_visitor = models.IntegerField()
    score_local = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: can you explain in more detail what is the relation between "won", "draw", "lost" , "score_visitor" and "score_local" ?

Comment: i want to make something like this
score_visitor ( for club_local ) and score_visitor ( for club_visitor )
score_visitor > score_local  ====> club_visitor.won +1  and club_local.lost +1

Comment: How do you know is a game is finished? Is it a post request that you are doing?

Comment: until now i try only to put results and return score and points to every club and calculate points .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't establish a relation between to fields even on the same model, but you can override the `save` method in Match you could implement a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) handler to be called after every `match` get saved.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Match)
def update_club_score(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Local won.
    if instance.score_local > instance.score_visitor:
        instance.club_local.won += 1
        instance.club_local.save()
        instance.club_visitor.lost += 1
        instance.club_visitor.save()
    # Local lost.
    if instance.score_local < instance.score_visitor:
        instance.club_visitor.won += 1
        instance.club_visitor.save()
        instance.club_local.lost += 1
        instance.club_local.save()
    # Draw
    if instance.score_local == instance.score_visitor:
        instance.club_local.draw += 1
        instance.club_local.save()
        instance.club_visitor.draw += 1
        instance.club_visitor.save()
```

Comment: @omarahmed Ok, please always remember to upvote or/and select the answers that help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to **update the fields of your models** somehow.

I would suggest something like:

First, write a function that **gets you the clubs** from the database:

```
def get_clubs(local_club_id, visitor_club_id):
    local_club = Club.objects.filter(pk=self.local_club_id)[0]
    visitor_club = Club.objects.filter(pk=self.visitor_club_id)[0]
    return local_club, visitor_club
```

And then you can **update the wins and losts** appropriately (in your `views.py`):

```
def update_scores(request):
    match = request.match
    club_local, club_visitor = get_clubs(match.club_local.pk, match.club_visitor.pk)
    if match.score_local > match.score_visitor:
        # home team won
        club_local.update(won=match.club_local.won + 1)
        club_visitor.update(lost=match.club_visitor.lost + 1)
    elif match.score_visitor > match.score_local:
        # away team won
        club_visitor.update(won=match.club_visitor.won + 1)
        club_local.update(lost=match.club_local.lost + 1)
    else:
        # it's a draw
        club_local.update(draw=match.club_local.draw + 1)
        club_visitor.update(draw=match.club_visitor.draw + 1)
```

After that your property function should work as expected.

Comment: This is not the best way to do this, you're traversing the whole list of matches every time.  When a match ends, just update those clubs related to it. Simple.

Comment: A more suitable way to go is as @andreihondrari states in his answer(overriding save ) or by a signal handler just like mine.

Comment: just i want to update "won" (lost or draw ) fields after adding a new match .. i tried to use post_save signal but still not working ..
i added this function first in "Match" class
def points(self):
        if self.score_local > self.score_visitor:
            return (self.club_local.won)+1 and (self.club_visitor.lost)+1
        elif self.score_local < self.score_visitor:
            return (self.club_local.lost)+1 and (self.club_visitor.won)+1
        else:
            return (self.club_local.draw)+1 and (self.club_visitor.draw)+1
post_save.connect(Club.teampoints, sender=Match)

Comment: yes, ofc. no need to iterate over all games everytime (it will get wrong results as well). However, it was just as an example how an update query will work. You can make the above as a function and call it only a game is finished.